# ErrorException in Validator.php line 2631: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

While doing validation I am trying to write an anonymous function to check apply a Rule but getting error, without the anonymous function code is working correctly

```php
$validateRules = [
    'user_id'   => ['required','array'],
    'user_id.*' => ['bail','required','regex:/^[1-9][0-9]*$/','exists:users,id,deleted_at,NULL','distinct',
          function($attribute, $value, $fail){
             dd($value);
          }
    ]
];
```

While validating if all other validations are cleared it should go inside this function

Error Log

```
ErrorException: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:2631
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'strpos() expect...', '/code/community...', 2631, Array)
#1 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(2631): strpos(Object(Closure), ':')
#2 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(2599): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->parseStringRule(Object(Closure))
#3 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(2580): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->parseRule(Object(Closure))
#4 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(2561): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->getRule('user_id.0', Array)
#5 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(589): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->hasRule('user_id.0', Array)
#6 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(564): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->passesOptionalCheck('user_id.0')
#7 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(481): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->isValidatable('Bail', 'user_id.0', '6')
#8 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(425): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->validate('user_id.0', 'Bail')
#9 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.php(24): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->passes()
#10 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/FoundationServiceProvider.php(41): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest->validate()
```

More to the previous Backlog

```
#11 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1031): Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider->Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\{closure}(Object(App\Modules\Auth\Requests\DeleteUserRequest), Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#12 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(994): Illuminate\Container\Container->fireCallbackArray(Object(App\Modules\Auth\Requests\DeleteUserRequest), Array)
#13 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(648): Illuminate\Container\Container->fireResolvingCallbacks('App\\Modules\\Aut...', Object(App\Modules\Auth\Requests\DeleteUserRequest))
#14 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Modules\\Aut...', Array)
#15 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(85): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Modules\\Aut...')
#16 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(58): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->transformDependency(Object(ReflectionParameter), Array, Array)
#17 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->resolveMethodDependencies(Array, Object(ReflectionMethod))
#18 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(143): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->resolveClassMethodDependencies(Array, Object(App\Modules\Auth\Controllers\UserController), 'deleteCompanyUs...')
#19 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Modules\Auth\Controllers\UserController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'deleteCompanyUs...')
#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#25 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Modules\Auth\Controllers\UserController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'deleteCompanyUs...')
#26 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Modules\\Aut...', 'deleteCompanyUs...')
#27 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /code/community_api/app/Http/Middleware/Api.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\Api->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#34 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /code/community_api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Middleware/RefreshToken.php(28): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 [internal function]: Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#39 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 /code/community_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /code/community_api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Middleware/GetUserFromToken.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware you cant use anonymous functions in the validation logic.  But you could look at FormRequests which have a before and after function hook.

Comment: @ColinMD we can use how I have written I have used it before, but this is the first time I am facing such an issue.

Comment: @vrnair24 can you post the backlog, maybe your issue is not with that validation

Comment: @N69S I am new to stackoverflow so I have added in a way I understand if u need more information please do ask.

Comment: @vrnair24 so the validation above is the one in `DeleteUserRequest` class ? wich laravel version are you using ?

Comment: I am using Larave 5.3 at present yet to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a mention of the possible use on a `Closure` as a validator parameter in laravel 5.3 except `extend()` method

```php
Validator::extend('foo', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            dd($value);
        });
$validateRules = [
    'user_id'   => ['required','array'],
    'user_id.*' => ['bail','required','integer','exists:users,id,deleted_at,NULL','distinct','foo']
];
```